# How to make google form fill itself automatically

Tags: javascript, python, web

introduce me as a student at a vocational high school, because learning is currently based online I have to fill in attendance on Google forms every day, the problem is that sometimes I forget to fill in the absences and my question is whether it is possible to create a program to fill out Google Forms online. automatically?, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Also that would be cheating. Set an alarm on your phone

Answer (score 0):

you should check out the blog post on medium.com
https://medium.com/swlh/automatically-filling-multiple-responses-into-a-google-form-with-selenium-and-python-176340c5220d

Answer (score 0):

#### Just a high level overview

I don't wish to be marked as someone who helps people how to cheat. That being said, if you manage to jump through all the hoops I think you will actually learn quite a bit. So here we go:

- You will need to setup a repeated job somewhere that will execute your task. If you don't do that, then setting up the alarm clock will be necessary anyways. It could be a cron job on a server, it could be a scheduled task on your computer. Bottom line it could be perpetually running task on your laptop - which would be prone to errors due to sleep, battery discharge etc. There are a lot of tools for running tasks, just pick one.
- You will need to find yourself a tool for web automation. This can be selenium, puppeteer, playwright or something similar. In this tool you will have to code in the way to fill in the form. E.g. accessing the form, authentication, filling the values where appropriate. Basic coding skills or a lot of google-fu will be necessary.
- Now comes the potential kicker - google forms might or might not be protected by captcha. If not, then you are likely done if your solution is robust enough to withstand a power outage and for example report failure so that you could fill in the values and go start debugging. If yes, you will need to register for a captcha solving service and link your solution so that is can bypass the captcha. It won't cost much however it's somewhat a hassle.

After all this is done, you have:

- Learned quite a bit about coding, webpage structure, html requests etc. congratulations.
- Spent several days learning, debugging, swearing and possibly praying in no particular order.
- Probably broken quite a few school rules. But well, this is your life.

Now the alarm clock sounds almost better, right?